# Why is getResponseHeader('content-type') returning 'text/xml' when the server is sending application/json?

Tags: javascript, ajax

This is an ajax call. The ajax library is

```js
var ajax = {
    initialize: function() {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            this.http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            this.http = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
        }
        if (!this.http) {
            alert('Cannot create an XmlHttp instance.');
        }
        if (this.http.overrideMimeType) {
            this.http.overrideMimeType('text/xml');
        }
    },
    exec: function(method, url, params, callback) {
        params = params || '';
        this.callback = callback || null;
        if ((method == 'GET') && (params != '')) {
            url    = url + (url.indexOf('?') > -1 ? '&' : '?') + params;
            params = null;
        }
        url = url + (url.indexOf('?') > -1 ? '&' : '?') + new Date().getTime();
        var self = this;
        this.http.open(method, url, (this.callback == null ? false : true));
        this.http.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
        if (method == 'POST') {
            this.http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        }
        if (this.callback != null) {
            this.http.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (self.http.readyState == 4) {
                    // DEBUGGING: TWO console.log() CALLS ADDED HERE
                    console.log(this);
                    console.log(this.getResponseHeader('content-type'));
                    return self.callback(self.http.responseText, self.http.status, this.getResponseHeader('content-type'));
                }
            }
        }
        this.http.send(params);
        if (this.callback == null) {
            return this.http.responseText;
        }
    },
    eval: function(json) {
        return JSON && JSON.parse(json) || eval('(' + json + ')'); // Use JSON.parse() if available; eval() otherwise.
    },
    serialize: function(obj, prefix) {
        var str = [];
        for (var p in obj) {
            var k = prefix ? prefix + '[' + p + ']' : p, v = obj[p];
            str.push((typeof v == 'object') ?
                serialize(v, k) :
                encodeURIComponent(k) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(v));
        }
        return str.join('&');
    }
}
ajax.initialize();
```

The server is returning a response with `Content-Type: application/json` (confirmed by the Network tab of Chromium’s debugger); but the javascript is detecting it as `text/xml` (confirmed by the console tab of the same debugger).

Full HTTP response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable
Date: Mon, 19 Sep 2016 13:31:35 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Length: 173
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=99
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/json
```

In the console, the XMLHttpRequest object is logged, and then the response from `getResponseHeader('content-type')`. The latter is `text/xml`. Why?

According to the log, `XMLHttpRequest.responseType` is an empty string.

Comment: `this.http.overrideMimeType('text/xml');` wonder what is overriding the mime type?

Comment: For flip's sake! Now I feel stupid.

Comment: `HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable` - also looks like you got an error

Comment: quick, delete the question, only I know :p

Comment: @JaromandaX. The 406 is fine: it means "credit card payment failed", and the calling javascript code handles this gracefully by extracting the error message (set by the payment gateway) from the JSON response, and displaying it. (If it was a 200, it wouldn't display anything, merely redirect to the receipt page.)